# Indicate that an uploaded file is present in edit form -- paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-forms

In my current solution, I am able to put a checkbox in the `edit` form so that users can delete attachment. However, there is no indication for the user that a file has been uploaded, the name of that file, etc. so that he can decide whether to delete.

Right now the form look like this. The first `material` is an existing one, the next 3 are due to

```
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    3.times { @post.post_materials.new }
  end
```

As you can see, it's very hard to distinguish between them. Ideally, I want the first material file name to appear somehow.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9IgwbV2.png]

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  Materials:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :materials, :html => { :multipart => true } do |materials_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= materials_form.label :asset %>
        <%= materials_form.file_field :asset %>

        <%= materials_form.label :_destroy, class: "checkbox inline" do %>
          Remove attachment <%= materials_form.check_box :_destroy %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running paperclip's [generator](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#migrations) creates a migration to add 4 attributes on your model, as you can see [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage). These attributes are:

```
<attachment>_file_name
<attachment>_file_size
<attachment>_content_type
<attachment>_updated_at
```

So, If you ran the generator this way: `rails generate paperclip post_material asset`, on your `PostMaterial` model, you will have these attributes:

```
asset_file_name
asset_file_size
asset_content_type
asset_updated_at
```

Then, on your code you can do something like this:

```
if materials_form.object.asset.exists? #object represents the current post_material instance
  #show a label with object.asset_file_name
else
  #render materials_form.file_field :asset
end
```

Comment: The key point here is that I can access `material` by using `materials_form.object`. Thank you!

Comment: Worth noting that `exists?` is slow especially if the file is on a storage provider. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#checking-a-file-exists for info